# Get multiple relation with same name in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to get 4 relations on User Model with same name, this is for blade file where I have to show profile data for all users

So I can do `$user->person->location;`

I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined relationship [Doctor AS Person] on model [App\User].
```

If there is another good solution please suggest it

**Controller**

```
    public function profile()
    {
        $curr_user = Auth::user();

        if($curr_user->hasrole('Doctor'))
        {
            $user = $curr_user->with('Doctor AS Person')->get();
        }
        elseif($curr_user->hasrole('Patient'))
        {
            $user = $curr_user->with('Patient AS Person')->get();
        }
        if($curr_user->hasrole('Pharmacy'))
        {
            $user = $curr_user->with('Pharmacy AS Person')->get();
        }
        if($curr_user->hasrole('Lab'))
        {
            $user = $curr_user->with('Lab AS Person')->get();
        }

        return view('admin.profile', compact('user'));
    }
```

**User Model**

```
    public function doctor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Doctor');
    }

    public function patient()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Patient');
    }

    public function pharmacy()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Pharmacy');
    }

    public function lab()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Lab');
    }
```

Comment: laravel eager load not support alias, remove alias `AS` in `with` method

Comment: What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

laravel eager load does not support alias, so you can reassign relationship name

```
$user = $curr_user;
if($curr_user->hasrole('Doctor'))
{
    $user->Person = $user->Doctor;
}
else if ($curr_user->hasrole('Patient'))
{
    $user->Person = $user->Patient;
}...
```